# Finding the sum of a series using method of differences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was given this question on an assignment and was unable to get the same answer. Can someone explain this to me please. Thank you.

Using method of differences prove that $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+2)}=\frac{n(an+b)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are to be found.

Hence show that
$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{r(r+2)}=\frac{n(4n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: You said you were unable to get the same answer. Can you show what answer you did get, and how you got to that result?

Comment: Hint: show that $\frac{1}{r(r+2)} = \frac{1}{2r} - \frac{1}{2r + 2}$.

Comment: I got the first part of the question but I don't really understand the last part with $\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}$

Comment: Use $\sum_{r = n+1}^{2n} \frac1{r(r+2)} = \sum_{r = 1}^{2n} \frac1{r(r+2)} - \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac1{r(r+2)}$

Comment: Ohhh, okay I got it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{r(r+2)}$$= $\frac{1}{2} $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+2}$$
=\frac{1}{2} (1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2})
=\frac{3n^2+5n}{8n^2+12n+4}
=\frac{n(3n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$
${a}=3 , {b}=5$

$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{r(r+2)}$$= ($\frac{1}{2} $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+2} $) - ($\frac{1}{2} $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+2}$)

$\frac{1}{2} $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+2}= \frac{1}{2} (1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2})
=\frac{6n^2+5n}{8n^2+12n+4} $

$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{r(r+2)}=\frac{6n^2+5n}{8n^2+12n+4}-=\frac{n(3n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)} 
=\frac{6n^2+5n}{4(n+1)(2n+1)}-=\frac{n(3n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}
=\frac{4n^2+5n}{4(n+1)(n+2)(2n+1)}
=\frac{n(4n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)(2n+1)}$$